# Using yum with a proxy

Tags: proxy, centos, yum

I am trying to using yum with a proxy but when I do:

```
yum list
```

I get:

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: HTTP Error 407 - Proxy Authentication Required ...
```

To configure yum, I tried two solution:

1. add in /etc/yum.conf:`proxy=http://username:password@yourproxy:8080/`
2. and: `export http_proxy=http://username:password@yourproxy:8080/`

But when I export the variable, curl works.

OS: `CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)`

PS1: The proxy is under Windows, is it possible that the problem is NTLM even if curl works ?

PS2: We are using another proxy and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The first one should work. This is what I am using

```
 proxy=http://webproxy.company.com:3128/
```

Are you certain your proxy is listening on 8080? That seems like an odd port to pick for a proxy server.

Comment: This socket is just for the example, but with the real port it does'nt work (but curl does).

Comment: What are you curling?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the second method you are setting the proxy on your current profile , so when you use

> sudo yum ----

you are not using the proxy you have set.
Just export the proxy from the same profile you are using the command from.